# HtmlInputHidden with java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, jsf-2, serializable

I changed the context param `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` from `server` to `client` in my JSF application but now I get:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputHidden
```

This breaks the view rendering.

As `HtmlInputHidden` is from a third party jar, I can't implement it myself.

Is there any way to solve such problem?

Comment: Why is the component in your view state to begin with? This seems wrong, component trees should be rebuilt based on the view state and the templates, not deserialised from it.

Comment: @millimoose, sorry, but I didn't understand your question.

Comment: What I tried to say is `HtmlInputHidden` (or any other component implementation) really has no business being serialised in the first place, and thus shouldn't need to be `Serializable` at all. In JSF, whole components aren't serialised directly; you only serialise a part of their state - returned from the `saveState()` method wrapped in a `Serializable` object. So I'd try poking at the code/debugger to see if you can find out why a `HtmlInputHidden` instance is even being serialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `transient` keyword in `HtmlInputHidden` declaration:

```
private transient HtmlInputHidden htmlInputHidden;
```

As @millimoose said, `saveSate()` method controls the state; not the serialization.